# Google-Calendar offline?

Tags: google-calendar

How can I have my google-calendars availabe offline on my PC as well?

I have been using dropbox to sync my calendars in ics-format between different PC's instead of using google calendar. The disadvantage of google-calendar is, that I can only see my appointments when online.

Now I want to sync my calendars with my android device as well, what does not seem to be possible yet.

So I am planning to have an online copy of all my appointments on Google-Calendar, in order to sync them with my Android device. At the same time I want to be able to access my appointments offline (have an offline copy of each calendar on my PC's synced via Dropbox).

Is there a way to automatically duplicate and sync Coogle-Calendars with Ubuntu to achieve this?

This question is a follow-up, also see my related question, please: https://askubuntu.com/questions/26431/how-to-sync-calendar-with-android-without-google

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Google Calendar (and Contacts) can be synced with Gnome Evolution, which comes with Ubuntu.  Evolution can be used off-line.   The Google Calendar page [How to sync google calendar with evolution in ubuntu 9.04](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Calendar/thread?tid=28cb4a5d7afbd49a&hl=en)  is a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks, Evolution is really working with google-calendar when offline, what was not the case for Thunderbird-Lightning. I was hoping for a solution that works with Lightning too, since I do not like the interface of Evolution, but you answered my question perfectly. CU

Answer (score 4):

From google calendar offline feature:

> Install offline access for Google
>   Calendar Google Calendar will give you
>   read-only access to your calendars
>   when there is no internet connection.
>   This feature will download your events
>   onto this computer. Please make sure
>   you are not using a public or shared
>   computer. You will need Gears for
>   offline access, and the installer will
>   restart your browser.

You can have an *"offline version"* of your google calendar, which will give you *"read-only access"* when you have no internet connection. Unfortunately, *"read-only access"* means that you won't be able to make changes, add appointments or modify anything in your calendar when not having an internet connection.

When you gain access to the net again, you can do as many modifications as you wish, which will auto-sync with your *"offline version"* in order to keep your device up to date.

I have tested this feature in computers: desktop and laptops (even netbooks) using MS based systems and a few distributions of linux in several versions but never in android.

You give it a try: in the google-calendar, beside your name, you will find a link with the label "offline", and after clicking it you will be adviced about the functionality of this feature and will be led to the right area where to activate in your own calendar.

Good luck!

A screenshot is placed here for you to see this feature's welcome message:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Having read only access when offline is better than nothing.