# Google calendar sync for offline use

Tags: calendar, offline

I can't see how to access the Google calendar app off line. It may not yet be possible, but I live in an area with poor reception and off line access would be very useful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google-Calendar offline?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/26462/google-calendar-offline)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way, in my opinion, is to install `thunderbird` and then the add ons `lightning` and `provider for google calendar` (then adding your google calendar can be done with a few clicks. You can possibly use evolution or other software but I always prefer thunderbird.
You can also install the thunderbird add on `gContactSync` in order to have google contacts offline too.